# delete several row mysql database together?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to delete "several row mysql database" together after select with checkbox in "codeigniter", but my function not work:(my problem is in "function delete()"). What is it?

```
function delete(){
    $delete = $this->input->post('delete'); // this is array => "delete[]" . value this is "id" it row in database.
    for($i=0;$i<count($delete);$i++) {
        $this->db->delete('My_Table', array('id' => $delete[$i])); 
    }
    }
```

Comment: So what is error message or more detail please?

Comment: What do you get if you `print_r($delete);` before the for loop? Does it contain what you think it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have an array of ID's in your `$delete` variable, you can do the following:

```
if(is_array($delete) && count($delete) > 0)
{
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `My_Table` WHERE `id` IN (" . implode(", ", $delete) . ")");
}
```